# What do they mean by "scripting language" in IT job advertisements?

Tags: recruitment

I've seen advertisements where there was a line like:

- *[We require] knowledge of a scripting language, e.g. JavaScript*
- *[We require] knowledge of a scripting language, e.g. Bash*

Why is the scriptness of a language such a big deal? If you know a programming language that is non-scripting, it takes very little to understand the scriptness. Or is it just me? I know this question might seem off-topic, but I'd actually wanted to get an answer which takes the business context into consideration.

Another thing I wanted to ask is if I understand the business concept of a scripting language correctly. I've used R, Matlab, Python, VBA, MSSQL - as far as I know, they're scripting languages. Does it mean that I satisfy the condition *[We require] knowledge of a scripting language, e.g. Bash*?

Comment: We can't tell you what individual companies mean in job adverts.

Comment: I wouldn't call R, Matlab, or MSSQL scripting languages. Python and VBA certainly are.

Comment: *"it takes very little to understand the scriptness"* - let's say it takes remarkably less to learn a second language than the first one. But someone who knows just some language but not language X will be far from being able to start doing X right now. There is still practice, running into all kinds of errors, wondering about syntax, research and experiment...

Comment: **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language**

Comment: @GregoryCurrie: SQL is not a scripting language, but we still call them "SQL scripts" for some bizarre reason (perhaps just alliteration). Maybe we've confused the non-programmers?

Comment: @Kevin SQL is definitely a scripting language. It is not compiled as a whole, and could be put in scripts that execute commands automatically one after the other.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yes they are. Again, they are compiled only at runtime, and each command typically could be executed individually or in a batch.

Comment: @Kevin, I think the main reason SQL is often referred to as a "script" is because files containing code are frequently applied to operate upon or modify an online system. I primarily concern myself with development (and rarely if ever distribute "scripts" to users), and wouldn't readily have thought of SQL as a scripting language, but SQL also provides extensive support for those who primarily perform database administration, where SQL obviously does perform the role of a scripting language. Complicated queries stored as SQL files and distributed to users, also seem to meet the criteria.

Comment: @rs.29 SQL is a query language.   It's in the name.

Comment: @Jack Those things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: scriping languages are deployed differently than compiled software. They probably want someone that has experience writing up scripts that get run onthefly or something... I wouldn't worry about it very much. It's likely that they're looking for someone with experience with them in general rather than that particular one. And job descriptions in general are usually written overly strict.

Comment: Yes, you satisfy that condition. Whenever you're in doubt, you should err on the side of applying for the position anyway.

Comment: Scripting languages are high-level langages that are often used within a software/ OS to automate stuffs. They are often preferred over programming languages that need to be *compiled* or *interpreted* as these are perceived as being more time-consuming and / or complicated. While it is easier to learn scripting languages if you have programming experience, some employers would prefer you already know it because they want you to work on some project immediately (experience may matter here).

Comment: Informally, people talk about a 'script' or 'scripting' when you're going to write software that only you (or your team) uses. Technical features of the language are not the important things here (interpreted, compiled, static typing, etc.), but it must be a language where it's easy to get something small running without too much hassle.  Usually the script is to automate some task, or make something easier. That may not sound spectacular, but for non-trivial development, some amount of scripting is always needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is they mean general-purpose scripting languages.

I believe that scripting languages are more accessible for non-programmers. They generally are easier to debug, faster to play around with, and generally are easier to integrate into various workflows.

So it's likely that they are just using terms that may appeal to the most number of candidates.

And I would think knowing a scripting language encourages the "automate first" mindset that in a lot of roles can really be a massive efficiency multiplier.

I would consider R and Matlab to not be general purpose scripting languages. MSSQL certainly isn't. I sort of doubt that VBA is. Python certainly is. But ultimately what really matters is what the company means, so when applying for a job, I'd certainly mention them all.

Comment: While VBA isn't really a general purpose scripting language, vbscript (which is a subset of it) is. It was pretty popular on Windows when you needed something better than Batch files before PowerShell became ubiquitous.

Answer (score 6):

> - [We require] knowledge of a scripting language, e.g. JavaScript
> - [We require] knowledge of a scripting language, e.g. Bash

The examples you give an indication of what it is they're looking for, and they seem to be different things.

If they're asking for a language like Bash, then it sounds like they want someone who can script and automated tasks for things like system administration or data processing - so I'd include languages like Bash/Zsh/etc, Python, Perl and Ruby.

On the other hand, if they're asking for JavaScript, it sounds more like a web development role - so they probably want JavaScript or one of the variants (TypeScript, CoffeeScript, etc).

Look at the rest of the job advent, and you should be able to understand from the context what they would want you to *actually achieve* with the scripting language, and that should give you an idea of which one(s) would be appropriate. If it's an advert for a data analyst then knowing R and Python sounds great. If it's for a frontend web developer, not so much. But as you said, if you know a few languages already, it's not hard to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

### What do they mean by "scripting language"...

As noted in the comments the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) page's first paragraph has the most common definition, for us old school folks the generally accepted qualifier was that a script was interpreted rather than compiled. But the lines have been blurred quite a bit over the years as technology evolves.

### e.g. JavaScript or e.g. Bash or ...

While reasonably competent developers can pick up the basics of other languages fairly quickly, there are significant differences between some languages, and proficiency in JavaScript doesn't necessarily translate immediately to shell scripting such as Bash.

In the examples you provide, I would associate the language with a similar language, i.e., bash with other shells such as Broune, C, or Kron. I know many excellent JavaScript developers that can't even open and operate in a shell with any proficiency, so don't assume knowledge of one 'scripting language' automatically equates to a knowledge of all.

### Why is the scriptness of a language such a big deal?

Not sure how this applies globally, but here in the US there is often a contractual, liability, and insurance cost difference between writing and delivering scripted tools verses compiled programs and applications.

Why this is I don't really know, perhaps a good question for the legal StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) states (emphasis mine):

> A scripting language or script language is a programming language for a runtime system that automates the execution of **tasks that would otherwise be performed individually** by a human operator.

Putting formal definitions and specific examples of scripting languages aside, job ads seem to use it to describe writing a piece of code that interfaces with one or multiple systems to perform tasks that are cumbersome or difficult to achieve through other means. Scripting favors speed over exacting development standards as the code might only be used once.

I like to see a scripting language as a context-specific automation tool. The employer is not looking for someone with general 'scripting' experience, but for someone who has automated tasks in a specific domain: R will do you little good as a *nix sysadmin. SQL won't help you configure a domain controller. And powershell won't get you far as a data analist.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, scriptinc language began as technical term, nontechnical people picked up on and now use it without understanding it.

I had talks with non programmers (recruiting and such), who thought scripting languages are something completly different from normal languages, and didn't understand that they are turing complete and can calculate everything other languages can too.
So they thought they were being specific, while they were being nonsensical.

Other companies write it to appeal to a certain kind of programmers:
Scripting languages typcially having dynamic typing and have an interpreter (Python for example also has a compiler, but almost everybody uses an interpreted version). Some programmers hate that, others love it, some don't care. When you are willing to do work in a scripting language, you have shown willingness to work with dynamictyping/interpreter environment, and thus you could be trained up in another scripting language.
I knew a company who did a lot of Ruby, which isn't that common around here.
They wanted Perl, Python and JS programmers because their thinking was they would adapt fast to a Ruby mindest.

So by having Python you would tick that box.

Answer (score 1):

"Scripting languages" are used by two totally separate groups of developers: One developers who write code, use compilers, and often use build scripts to help developing code, or scripts to install software etc. I need a bit of that in my work, the guys creating our software installers need a lot. It would be bad if I knew nothing about bash and so on, but not knowing much is no problem. It's only a tiny percentage of my work, and I don't need to be an expert - just enough to get things to work.

And two, developers who create web applications, using things like JavaScript, PHP and the like, not just plain html. For that kind of job, these kinds of scripting languages are essential.

Comment: In all my jobs, both scripting with Bash, Ansible playbooks, one-off JS/node/Python/Perl, SQL, YAML, etc, and regular programming with both interpreted (Python, Node, PHP) and compiled (C#, Java, Go, Qt) have been equal in amounts that I presume it's hard to find developers that don't have exposure to all of the styles (of course not these specific languages, but in general).

Answer (score 1):

A programming language is compiled, while a scripting language is interpreted at runtime.  There is more to it than that, but that is the difference at the highest level.  Do not think that just because a language is scripted, that there isnt a high level of complexity to it.

You are correct that if you know how to program in one language, you are probably capable of programming in another.  However, if a company specifically calls out a specific scripting language, they expect you to have some level of proficiency and hit the ground running.

For example, if they expect you to know JavaScript, it is highly likely you are applying for a web development position.  They are going to expect you to have a deep understanding of JavaScript, which is extremely common in web development.

If a company is asking for Bash, you are likely applying for a UNIX/Linux systems administration position.  Bash is the most commonly used shell in that environment.  Someone in that position is going to need to be able to understand Bash to understand what is running and how in that environment.  Likely, if they are requiring Bash, much of the infrastructure is being managed by Bash scripts.

Thinking, you can just figure it out as you go will not go well.  It is no different than thinking that if you know English, and they require German.  Sure both are Germanic languages, but if someone hands you a book in German, you might be able to pick out bits and pieces, but you are not going to truly understand it.

Comment: *while a scripting language is interpreted at runtime*. That's an old time definition which hasn't made sense for at least 35 years. Most languages which are commonly referred to as "scripting languages" aren't interpreted. Languages like Perl, Python, Ruby, Lua and JavaScript are compiled. They just don't require a separated compilation stage which produces a binary.

Comment: @Abigail who cares?  thats irrelevant to the question being asked.  and it still holds true for many scripting languages.

Comment: Hmmm, the question is what do they mean by scripting languages, so, yeah, I think defining what a scripting language is is relevant.

Comment: @Abigail not really.  its about why he would need to know them.  he thinks if its just a scripting language, its not important